# Delete extra character from strings

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I have a bunch of strings with an extra number at the end, like so 
`"ABC12345"`

I want to remove the extra number at the end, before the quotes.

This: `ABC\d{5}` selects the whole string without the quotes. How can I select the last number and delete it?

Comment: Please specify desired output.

Comment: Something like `(ABC)\d{5}` with a replacement text of `\1`; the brackets around the first part capture the matched text, and if the entire regex matches the replacement text of `\1` is the first capture, which is the part before the number.

Comment: Try `ABC\d{4}\K\d"` and replace with `"`

Answer (score 0):

You can match any numbers that prepend the end of line `$`.

```
\d*$
```

In case your file does actually contains quotes, it is even easier

```
\d*"
```

[example](https://rubular.com/r/fPCJVt5iEV)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using notepad++ try the following steps

1. Paste the this expression in the find input box `\d{5}\"`
2. `"` in the replace input box
3. Select Regular Expression radio button
4. Click replace or replace All

Using Javascript:

```
<script>
    var str = 'ABCD12345  SJFKDFJ87654';
    console.log(str.replace(/\d{5}/g, ''));
</script>
```